# meteorjs: simple reusable template with route-specific data contexts using Iron Router

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-blaze

tldr: how to insert a single html template in various spots in Meteor JS app, each using unique data context for specified routes (using Iron Router).

`Template.images`:

```
<template name="images">
  {{#each dataSource }}
    <img id="{{ id }}" src="{{ src }}">
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Where `dataSource` is data: `helpers.js` **assumption here**: `Template.images` should be the source of the helpers (data), since they are ultimately rendered in this template.

```
Template.images.helpers({
  funData: function () {
    return [
      { id: 'fun' , src : 'fun/pink.png' },
      { id: 'fun' , src : 'fun/blue.png' }
    ]
  },
  painData: function () {
    return [
      { id: 'pain' , src : 'pain/black.png' },
      { id: 'pain' , src : 'pain/gray.png' },
      { id: 'pain' , src : 'pain/moargrey.png' },
      { id: 'pain' , src : 'pain/white.png' }
    ]
  },
  loveData: function () {
    return [
      { id: 'love' , src : 'love/orange.png' },
      { id: 'love' , src : 'love/yellow.png' },
      { id: 'love' , src : 'love/blue.png' }
    ]
  }
});
```

I have MANY of these fooData, barData, etc collections, they are inserted as an arg (wrong term)  within `Template.images` via `dataSource`.

Certain routes yield `Template.images` multiple times, each with unique data context.  IOW I will need to configure the router / templates to access arbitrarily many specific `dataSources`. **Can I do something like this?**

```
<template name="myTemplate1">
  <h1>FUN</h1>  
  {{> images funData }}
</template>

<template name="myTemplate2">
  <h1>PAIN and LOVE</h1>  
  {{> images painData loveData }}
</template>
```

Then in my router (or a controller?) something like:

```
Router.map({

  this.route('myTemplate1', {
    data : function () {        // 1. set data context
      dataSource : funData      // how to set this?! 
    }
  })

  this.route('myTemplate2', {
    data : function () {         // 2. fetching multiple helpers?
      dataSource : [painData,loveData]      // set to array ?! 
    }
  })
})
```

**Summary**: How to use Meteor JS to send arbitrarily many dataset to the same template and render them in various specified templates throughout the app.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider doing the following:

- **Instead of returning the data from the template helpers, you should consider [Publishing your Collection Data](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish)**
- **Then subscribe to the data from withing your routes using the [waitOn](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#the-waiton-option) option, and also  [Returning Templates with Data](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#rendering-templates-with-data)**

Side note: *Keep in mind that the helper functions you've defined are only accessible from the "images" template*